# Mathematical Expression takes too long to even display

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I have the following expression, that I obtain in the following way:

```
$Assumptions = {M > 0, a > 0, r > 0, a < M, w > 0,e >= 0, d >= 0,lpl >= 0};
f2[r_] := Δ2[r]/(k[r] + a^2) // Simplify;
Gaos[r_] := (k'[r] Δ2[r])/(2 (k[r] + a^2)^2) // FullSimplify
KKaos = (k[r] + a^2) ω - a m // Simplify;
Vaos = (KKaos^2 - Δ2[r] λ)/(k[r] + a^2)^2 - Gaos[r]^2 - f2[r] Gaos'[r] // Simplify;
eqnaos = f2[r]^2 R''[r] + f2'[r] f2[r] R'[r] + Vaos R[r] ;

R[r_] := Exp[kk r] r^AA H2[r];
eqni = eqnaos/((E^(kk  r)) (r^AA) ) // Simplify ;
Clear[R]
ORDINF = 4;
H2[r_] := Sum[hhinf[i] r^-i, {i, 0, ORDINF + 10}];
ruleINF = {kk^2 -> -w^2, AA -> (-2 M w^2)/kk, kk^4 -> w^4, kk^6 -> -w^6};
serinf = Series[{eqni} //. ruleINF, {r, ∞, ORDINF}] // Chop;
```

This gives me a series expansion called `serinf`, which is in terms of the functions mentioned above. My main issue is that these functions are very complicated. So I first want to collect the coefficients of the series expansion upto a required order, which I do as follows:

```
eqnINF = Table[SeriesCoefficient[serinf[[1]], i] == 0, {i, 0, ORDINF}] // FullSimplify;
yINF = Table[hhinf[i], {i, 1, ORDINF - 1}];
```

So `eqnINF` is a table with the required coefficients now in terms of `\[CapitalDelta2][r]` and
`k[r]`. Now, I want to define these functions explicitly, and then solve the system of equations in `eqnINF` and `yINF`. So I define the functions:

```
f[r_] := (r/rs)^(2 e) (((1 - (rs/r)^(1 + e)) (2 + e + e (rs/r)^(1 + e))^2)/(16 (1 + e)^4 (1 + d^2L^2 g0^2 rs^2/(16 r^4)))) ((2 + e)^2 -e^2 (rs/r)^(1 +e));
g[r_] := (((r/rs)^(1 + e) - 1) ((r/rs)^(1 +e) (2 + e)^2 - e^2))/((1 + d^2 L^2 g0^2 rs^2/(16 r^4))((e + (r/rs)^(1 + e) (2 + e))^2)) // Simplify ;
h[r_] := r^2 (1 + d^2 L^2 g0^2 rs^2/(16 r^4));
k[r_] := Sqrt[g[r]/f[r]] h[r] // FullSimplify;
Δ2[r_] := g[r] h[r] + a^2 // FullSimplify;
```

Now even to just run `eqnINF` it takes hours, and so far I have not gotten an output. I think it it takes too long to substitute the functions I have now defined into the coefficients, and then to take the required derivatives. Earlier, I was defining all the functions in the beginning and the series expansion itself would not happen. But now, it looks like I've just traded in the time spent on the expansion to the time spent in actually plugging the functions back into the expansion.

My program requires it to further perform `Solve[eqnINF,yINF]`. Is there any way to increase efficiency on this? I also run a similar series expansion and that takes much less time, including the `Solve` and that also depends on all of these functions.

Edit: I have simplified a lot of the expressions, and I still am having the same issue. I have added the Mathematica notebook [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9b7vnd6wzr4405/Infinity%20Series%20Expansions%20AOS.nb?dl=0). I would like to obtain a series expansion at infinity, in terms of the parameters defined in the variable `eqnaos`

Comment: Have you tried avoiding all the `Simplify` calls? Those can be VERY slow, and you make one such call every time you call Gaos, KKaos, Vaos... Can some of the intermediate function definitions be done with `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`), since the latter forces recalculation at every call?

Comment: I did try using `Set`. But when I define `eqnaos` or the expansions, I have terms that are explicitly displayed as `f2'[r]` even though the function `f2[r]` has already been defined even before `eqnaos` and the series expansions have been defined.

Comment: Regarding the use of `Simplify` would it not be easier for the `Solve` command to work if my expressions were simplified enough?

Comment: I have tried replacing the equations with `Set` instead of `Set Delayed` and explicitly defining each derivative. Once I get the equations after simplification, I used `InputForm` and I defined a new variable using that (to not call Simplify each time) and then used Series on this. It still takes too long.

Comment: The function `hhinf[i]` is not defined in your given code snippet. Is this intentional?

Comment: @rowsi, yes. Those are the coefficients in the series expansion. As I have mentioned, the purpose of the rest of the program is to solve for the variables `hhinf[i]` for each `i` which is why I will be using a `Solve` as I have explained in the question.

Comment: You mentioned a working code in your post - would you be so kind to supply that one too?

Comment: @rowsi The working code is for expansion at a finite positive point, and not at infinity. I have attached a Mathematica notebook after a lot of simplification, as as an edit to my post.